# wants to read a string if it has more than one value then show in output with single header values seperated by ||

Tags: scala

My input string in scala looks like below

```
val input = "US:value1,US:value2,France:value3"
```

and I would like to have a output string like

```
val output = "US:value1||value2,France:value3"
```

since US has 2 values from the input in the output it should show as `US:value1||value2` and as France has only one value, the out put should look like `France:value3` kindly help me to code this in Scala

Comment: It's easier to offer code that does work if you first post code that doesn't work. SO isn't supposed to be a do-my-homework-for-me site.

Comment: I am new to Scala I have no clue how to code this, hence I posted here if anyone knows kindly help me with this.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: You do it by writing a program which does what you ask. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
input.split(",").map{value => (value.split(":")(0), value.split(":")(1))}.groupBy(_._1).map{ case(k,v) => k + ":" + v.map(_._2).mkString("||")}.mkString(",")
```

Or you can do this also:

```
val array = input.split(",").map{x => val arr = x.split(":")(arr(0),arr(1))}
array: Array[(String, String)] = Array((US,value1), (US,value2), (France,value3))

array.reduce((x, y) => if(x._1 == y._1) {(x._1, x._2 + "||" + y._2)} else {(x._1 + ":" + x._2, y._1 + ":" + y._2)})
// res26: (String, String) = (US:value1||value2,France:value3)
```